# os.remove - [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: python

If I run this as a separate module, it works fine but when I call this as a method in another py file, it stops after 2nd loop and throws the below error:

```py
for rownum in range(1, ws_read_execution_report_max_rows):
    shutil.copy(pdf_file_path, pdf_archive_path)
    if os.path.isfile(pdf_file_path):
        os.remove(pdf_file_path)
```

Throws exception:

```
[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Comment: (BTW, please fix your indentation).

Comment: check if the file you want to remove is open with another program.

Comment: Please also search for the error message online, it's not like you're the only person that ever encountered. Also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Anyhow, if this really _is_ happening or not depending on whether your code is called from a specific other process, we'd need a [mre] -- the shortest possible program that you've successfully tested to make the problem happen when that program is started without any changes -- so we can look at how that program is handling file descriptors and whether it's leaving an open handle on the file you want to delete.

Comment: What part of the error message is unclear?

Comment: First time i am posting a question here. Original code has the proper indentation.

Comment: Error throws on os.remove. I checked all the similar solutions but no breakthrough